# Problem with citation in table caption in LATEX

Tags: pdf, latex, overleaf

I'm writing my bachelor's thesis, and I'm trying to cite into a table caption. I've tried several things, and none works.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Number of parameters} & \textbf{Training data size}  \\ \hline
2019          & BERT\cite{devlin_bert_2019}           & 3.4E+08                       & 16GB                                  \\
2019          & DistilBERT\cite{sanh_distilbert_2020}     & 6.6E+07                       & 16GB                                  \\
2019          & ALBERT\cite{lan_albert_2020}         & 2.2E+08                       & 16GB                                  \\
2019          & RoBERTa\cite{liu_roberta_2019}        & 3.55E+08                      & 161GB                               \\
2020          & MegatronLM\cite{shoeybi_megatron-lm_2020}     & 8.3E+09                       & 174GB                                    \\
2020          & BETO\cite{canete_spanish_2020}           & 3.4E+08                       & 4GB                                   \\
2020          & GPT-3\cite{brown_language_2020}          & 1.75E+11                      & 570GB                                \\
2021          & Switch-C\cite{fedus_switch_2021}       & 1.57E+12                      & 745GB                        
\end{tabular}
\caption[Overview of latest large language models.]{Overview of latest large language models \protect \cite{bender_dangers_2021}.}
\label{table:overview_language_models}
\end{table}
```

This is my current approach, and I'm getting this:

[image]

This is working for me in figures, but not in tables. Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: You'll probably have to force this part to be lowercase, but unless you give us a test document that's just a guess